# Spring: define @RequestMapping value in a properties file

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations

Is it possible to define the value of a `@RequestMapping` annotation in Spring   by defining it in a properties file?

Actually, I do something like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/xxx")
public class MyController {
...
}
```

But I would like to store the path `/xxx` in a properties file. Why? For instance, it is less likely that I do mystakes in my templates if I rename the path in the controller.

In other framework this is allowed (see Symfony, for instance).

Comment: How about `@RequestMapping(System.getProperty("xxx.mapping.path", "/xxx"))`

Comment: @SMA that won't work. Annotation parameter values must be compile-time constants

Comment: @BohuslavBurghardt I just meant you define static final variable and use that variable here.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It should be possible to use placeholders in `@RequestMapping`, like for example `@RequestMapping("${foo.bar}")`. Take a look at the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-placeholders) for more details:

> Patterns in `@RequestMapping` annotations support `${…​`} placeholders against local properties and/or system properties and environment variables. This may be useful in cases where the path a controller is mapped to may need to be customized through configuration. For more information on placeholders, see the javadocs of the PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer class.

Comment: I was wondering about something like that (as done in `@Value`), but when I tried to call in `@RequestMapping` a key defined in the `application.properties` file, e.g. my.xx=/xxx, the IntelliJ Idea IDE reported the following problem: `Cannot resolve @PathVariable my.xx`. Any idea?

Comment: @JeanValjean And does it work when you run the app? IntelliJ inspections are not always perfect, so this might just be a false-positive

Comment: My mistake, if I add the definition in the application.properties file, everything is ok. The problem is when I try to load the string from another properties file. I have to find a way to read from it.

Comment: @JeanValjean Hello, have you found any ways to read from another properties file?

Answer (score 3):

Thx for the help. It is my contribution...
No dependencies are necessary because maven do everything by itself.

In the property file - use maven interpolation, such as below:

```
vs= v1

us= users
me= messages

url.user=${vs}/${us}
url.mess=${vs}/${me}
```

In your destiny file, for example controller/resource (in mycase):

```
@RestController
//@RequestMapping("v1/users") <<<<<<instead this
@RequestMapping("${url.user}")<<<<<<use this
@Api(value = "API RESTFUL)
public class UserResource {
//
```

Comment: Can this be used for a list of urls as well?

Answer (score 1):

As [bohuslav burghardt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1291150/bohuslav-burghardt) has mentioned this is totally possible.

So if you have a common domain stored in your `application.properties` file you can use placeholders to call it in your controller/s and even chain placeholders & text together.

For Example...
In your .properties file

```
app.domain = mydomain/v1
```

In the controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("${app.domain}/my-controller")
public class MyController {
```