# Spring Data REST: how to integrate custom endpoint without the need to hardcode its path element?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I use Spring Data REST with `spring.data.rest.base-path` property set as `/api`. If I extend `CrudRepository` for `User` entity,  I'll have an `/api/users` endpoint available in my RESTful service. Now assume, I want to add a custom endpoint to `/api/users` like this:

```java
@RepositoryRestController
public class UserController {

    @PatchMapping(path = "/users/{username}/update", produces = "application/hal+json")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public EntityModel<User> updateUser(@PathVariable String username, @RequestBody User user) {
        // some update logic here ... 
        return EntityModel.of(user);
    }

}
```

The path element in `@PatchMapping` annotation still contains explicit hardcoded `/users` part in it. Is there any programmatic way to replace it with the path variable to the collection resource of `User` type which is managed by Spring Data REST?

Comment: Well there is the `@RequestMapping` at the class level. But I'm not quite sure that is what you are looking for. https://stackabuse.com/spring-annotations-requestmapping-and-its-variants/ **Edit:** using `${...}` you can use placeholders which map to local properties (among others). https://stackoverflow.com/a/31904513/13211030

Comment: Either in `@RequestMapping` or in `@PatchMapping` I need to somehow replace `/users` part with something like `RepositoryEntityLinks.linkFor(User.class).toString()`

Comment: That looks impossible because the mappings are initialized during startup. Therefor you can only load it from property sources. Also isn't the User.class always going to be converted to a /user endpoint, and thus why the need for a dynamic mapping?

Comment: It's just the matter of refactoring. If I rename `User` into `Person`, I'll have manually replace `/users` with `/persons` for every `@GetMapping`, `@PostMapping`, etc...

Comment: Using placeholder like `"${users.path}"` and defining a special local property for this would be an option. Although, I will have to annotate my `CrudRepository` with `@RepositoryRestResource(path = "${users.path")` as well for consistency... Still, in search for better option.